# How i can avoid the distinct() of watchdog?

Tags: mysql, database, drupal, drupal-7

I want to avoid using distinct() in my code. I want some help in order to create a table that will keep the values that are taken from the db table watchdog and check if the next value has been taken. If the next value is in the table this value then will not insert in the table...I need a really help because i will end my module if i solve this think.Thanks in advance!!

```
// Begin building the query.
  $query = db_select('watchdog', 'th')
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->orderBy('wid')
    ->distinct()
    ->fields('th', array('variables', 'type', 'severity', 'message', 'wid'))
    ->limit(2000);

  // Fetch the result set.
  $result = $query  -> execute();

  // Loop through each item and add to $row.
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    blablablabla($row);
  }
}
```

i want the distinct values of the variables column. I do not want a theme table i just want a table with some values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make some empty array before the loop. Inside the loop check if the unique value exists in it. If it does just skip that loop iteration (continue). And if it doesn't store it in the array and do your blablabal();

```
    // query without distingc
//  print_r($results); print out array of results to see what field to take as unique

      $already_processed = array();

  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $unique_value = $row['some_unique_field'];
    if (in_array($unique_value, $already_processed)) continue;
    $already_processed[] = $unique_value;
    blablabla($row);
  }
```

Something like that.

Comment: I am very new in drupal could you help with what you say?

Comment: That's not a "drupal thing" but basic PHP. Print out that $row variable and check what field is suitable for making a record unique. Then check for that field and store it, as I explained above.

Comment: i will do? $blabla = array(variables); over the loop? and how i will check in the loop if it this exists?? I am so comfused :'( :'(

Comment: There you go. This is (probably) slower than filtering results from database query.

Comment: you mean this would be slower that putting distinct()??

Comment: i have 1 more question: How i can now use one by one the values in the blablabla($row)??? Thank you so much. You saved me !!

Comment: Yes, that $already_processed contains the (unique!) list of fields. So if you need that just pass it as function parameter.

Comment: if i have this table in a hook_cron. When cron runs the table will be cleaned?